# Mysql Variable Calculation

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How would you calculate the difference in days between 2 variables in MySQL with php?

for instance, a rough example would be (the table is `users`, not sure where to put this):

```
    $vipdays = "UPDATE `vipdays` SUBDIFF(TO_DAYS(`vipdate`) - `vipdays`)
```

`vipdate` is in the sql date format, and needs to be converted to days from the `vipdate`. 
I think `TO_DAYS` does this, not sure though. After subtracting the vipdate (date became vip) and vipdays (vip days purchased), the variable vipdays would update to the correct number of days left for the user.

This sql query will run when vipdays are checked on the site, but the days need to reflect the correct number of days left.

Here is an update of what I have:

```
    $vipdate = $db->Query("SELECT TO_DAYS(vipdate) FROM `users`");
    $curdate = $db->Query("SELECT TO_DAYS(NOW())");
    $vipdays = $db->Query("SELECT premium FROM `users`");
    $daysremaining = $curdate - $vipdate;
    $remaining = $vipdays - $daysremaining;
    $db->Query("UPDATE `users` SET `premium`='{$remaining}'");
```

that is what I have so far...it would work if the sql syntax was correct. Can anyone help?

Comment: what is the condition from which u decide which `vipdate` is to be substracted from which other `vipdate`?? and do u want this to be done through `mysql` function or `PHP` scripting?

Comment: If you do not know what TO_DAYS does, try searching the web for it. It would have helped you a great deal in finding your answer yourself: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-days

Answer (score 0):

```
$pdate = str_replace("/", "-", $data['vipdate']);
$vipdate = strtotime($pdate);
$cdate = str_replace("/", "-", date("Y-m-d"));
$curdate = strtotime($cdate);
$vipdays = $data['premium'];
$vipdaysremaining = $data['remaining'];
```

Done and done. Works perfect. Thanks for all your help!